# Whenever I turn on my PC, it goes to a pure purple screen then it goes black

Tags: 14.04, boot

This happens with restarting too. When I restart it turns off just fine, but then when it turns back on, it goes to a purple screen and then black.

However it does turn on after I hold the power button until it turns off, and then turn it back on again. This isn't a crucial fix, just really inconvenient. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a desktop or a laptop? Holding the power button for a few seconds forces the power off on most laptops, most OS's will complain &/or cause filesystem corruption from a forced power off like that. Have/need any video drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Though it may not be a complete solution, when the screen is black you may try to access the terminal via Ctrl+Alt+F1/.../F6 and try to `sudo service lightdm restart`.

Comment: I tried using  Ctrl+Alt+T and it opened up asking for a password, when I put it in my PC turned on.  Thanks for the idea of opening the terminal, I never would've thought that.